# Neo4j Asymetric Relationships

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

Is there a way to make asymetric relationships in Neo4j?

The need is to have different costs depending on which direction the path is being traversed between two nodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There preferred way to do this is to create two edges between the same two nodes, in opposite directions, each with a property representing cost.

Technically, it would also be possible to create two properties on the same edge, for instance

```
(n:myLabel {name:'A'})-[r:MY_EDGE_TYPE {cost:'A,7,B,5'})->(m:myLabel {name:'B'})
```

But it does not look good to start with ;). Also, you would have to do additional computing in any cost calculation of total cost over a path.

Comment: I was starting to lean into a similar solution... thank you for confirming it makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

You could reference different attributes depending on what direction you come from, i.e:

```
(n1:Node)-[:EDGE {in: 5, out: 3}]->(n2:Node)
```

When you are traversing the relationship from `n1` to `n2` you would reference `out` to get a weight of 3, and when you're going from `n2` to `n1` you would reference `in` to get a weight of 5.

This seems like an antipattern to me though since you'll have to keep track of the direction. I would choose two relationships with one property if in any way possible.

Comment: That might work, at the expense of query simplicity though... thanks!

Comment: If you like living dangerously then you call also store it as a floating point number. Inbound weight in the integer part, outbound weight in the fraction part. But this sounds like something that will break spectacularly at some point.